# Color controlHIghlight / Ripple Effect (?)

Tags: android

[image]

what is the name of this effect/view?
and how can I customize this?

Comment: what do you want to do with this effect ?

Comment: wanna set different color for different fragment

Comment: this set  by default app:PrimaryColor

Comment: Do you mean you want to highlight a row of a recycler? because it look like that on the picture..

Answer (score 0):

This effect is by default by higher version of **LOLLIPOP**.

You can customize this effect by following ways : add this to your `ScrollView`.

By xml code :

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

By java Code :

```
findViewById(R.id.sobreScrollView).setOverScrollMode(ScrollView.OVER_SCROLL_NEV‌​ER);
```

Comment: wanna set different color for different fragment. how can I do this?

Comment: It uses app colorPrimary

Comment: is there any way to customize it for different fragment?

Comment: need to do like this , look into this http://www.androprogrammer.com/2015/08/change-android-application-theme-runtime.html